# URL Rewrite: PHP variable as directory

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Alright, how would I get something like:

```
domain.com/friends.php?id=Fred
```

Into something like:

```
domain.com/Fred/friends.php
```

Previously, I have used:

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9]+)$ profile.php?id=$1 [L]
```

To turn

```
domain.com/profile.php?id=Fred
```

Into

```
domain.com/Fred
```

I know there is a way to do it, I just don't have the knowledge of the operators that would put that extra 'friends.php' in the RewriteRule. Thanks for the help, if my explanation made sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close:

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9]+)/friends\.php$ friends.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Sure! One thing though. My CSS isnt showing up. What could be the cause?

Comment: Does it show up for other pages? What's your CSS file named? Are you sure the address is right when you link to it in your HTML?

Comment: Nevermind, silly me. Forgot that I needed a '../' Thanks for the help man! I have to wait a few more minutes to check off the answer.